# Ampscript Lookup Product Recommendation Table with Product Images, URLs and Names

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, lookup, sql

I have this table (Product_Recommendations) of recommended products (4) per email address.

[image]

I want to add these products into my email, using ampscript lookup. I tried the following, but it was erroring out in Marketing Cloud:

```
%%[

VAR @emailAddr, @p1_name, @p1_url, @p1_image 
set @emailAddr = EmailAddress("emailaddr") 
SET @p1_name = (Lookup("Product_Recommendation", "Product_Name_1" EmailAddress",@emailaddr)) 
SET @p1_url = (Lookup("Product_Recommendation", "Product_URL_1" EmailAddress",@emailaddr)) 
SET @p1_image = (Lookup("Product_Recommendation", "Product_Image_1" EmailAddress",@emailaddr))

]%%
```

Not sure what I am doing wrong. Thanks!

Comment: As @TravisNaughton mentioned in his answer, your @emailAddr var is only going to return `true` or `false` as the `EmailAddress()` function returns a booleen response depending on if the content inside is a valid email or not. This is likely your major issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To access the email address attribute you want to use [Attribute Value](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/attributevalue.htm) function. Also the syntax on the lookups doesn't need the extra brackets.

```
%[VAR @emailAddr, @p1_name, @p1_url, @p1_image 
SET @emailaddr = AttributeValue("emailaddr") 
SET @p1_name = Lookup("Product_Recommendation", "Product_Name_1" EmailAddress",@emailaddr)
SET @p1_url = Lookup("Product_Recommendation", "Product_URL_1" EmailAddress",@emailaddr) 
SET @p1_image = Lookup("Product_Recommendation", "Product_Image_1" EmailAddress",@emailaddr)]%%
```